# SBT AutoPlugin missing added artifact

Tags: sbt

I have written a couple of AutoPlugins to simplify my multi-project sbt build.

One of these AutoPlugins defines a `TaskKey[File]` and adds an artifact for the result of that task.

```
object PluginA extends AutoPlugin {
  val content: SettingKey[File] = taskKey[String]("")
  val generateArtifact: TaskKey[File] = taskKey[File]("generated artifact file")

  override lazy val projectSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = {
    addArtifact(
      Artifact("foo", "xml", "xml"), generateArtifact
    ).settings ++
      Seq(
        generateArtifact := {
          val bar = content.value
          ...
        }
      )
  }
}
```

Then I have another AutoPlugin that `requires` the plugin above to add some settings.

```
object PluginB extends AutoPlugin {
  override def requires: Plugins = PluginA
  override lazy val projectSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Seq(
    content := "..."
  )
}
```

All is well so far.
Now I try to add the new artifact to my projects in `build.sbt``

```
val someModule = (project in file("Module")).enablePlugins(PluginB, AndroidJar)
val someApp = (project in file("Application")).enablePlugins(PluginB, AndroidApp)
```

Sadly, when I enter `publishLocal` in my sbt console only the default artifacts are published, but not my new xml file. `show artifacts` doesn't list the artifact either.

However, I know the plugins and plugin settings are loaded, because `show generateArtifact` produces the desired file. It is only the artifact that gets lost somewhere.

**NOTE**

An (as far as I can see) similar setup without any sbt-android AutoPlugin yields the desired artifact, while it vanishes, if I add an sbt-android AutoPlugin.

I also played around with the order of plugins in `enablePlugins`.

I am using `"org.scala-android" %% "sbt-android" % "1.7.2"` and `sbt 0.13.13`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem myself.

After some digging I found that CorePlugin resets `artifacts`to `Nil`.

One has to require either `CorePlugin` or `JvmPlugin` in the plugin that adds the artifact to ensure that the settings doing the reset are loaded before the own `projectSettings`.

```
object PluginA extends AutoPlugin {
  override def requires: Plugins = JvmPlugin
  ...
}
```

The seeming relation to *sbt-android* was coincidental.